# Rounding Decimal Indian Rupees C#

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

I want to round off one decimal variable (ex Rs. 5.65) with 2 rules:

1. if the part after decimal (.65 in
   the example) in greater that 49, add
   1 to the part before decimal.(Make
   it 6)
2. If the part after decimal is less
   that 49(ex: 2.45) remove the part
   after decimal(Ex: Make it 2.00)

Please suggest a solution.

***EDIT*** Can anyone tell me how to achieve the same using TSQL and CrystalReport ???

Comment: use Math.Round() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: And what if it is 3.493 or 3.496? How about negative numbers?

Comment: It will always be up to 2 places of decimal, and since it's money there is no difference whether it's positive or negative.

Comment: Yes Richard, I have already tried something(Math.Round()) and it is not working as desired by me.

Comment: look at the other overloads for Math.Round, some of them allow you to specify the rounding logic.

Comment: If math.round won't work, here's another option... convert the number into a string. Split it by '.' take the last and check for >49 and add 1 for the first of the split string. Convert back it to decimal or float(whatever you need).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [`Math.Round(decimal, MidPointRounding)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx), it should do what you need.

Comment: The second parameter should be `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. when in doubt look at the System.Math object. In your case what you want is

```
Math.Round(SomeDecimal);
```

Comment: The problem is that it's making 12.50 12.00, while I want it to be 13.00

Answer (score 1):

```
iif(5.655 % Math.Round(5.6549, 2) > 0.49, Math.Ceiling(5.6549), Math.Floor(5.6549));

iif(5.655 % Math.Round(5.655, 2) > 0.49, Math.Ceiling(5.655), Math.Floor(5.655));
```

Comment: I think I've made a tiny mistake, not sure if it was after the decimal place or as you say "part after decimal (.65 in the example)", but you can see the idea here.